# $\sigma$-subadditivity (check my proof)

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

i have a general Problem with Proofs in mathematics, that I don't fully know when a proof is complete (enough) and that I sometimes don't know, that my way of approaching a proof makes sense in a theoretical level. I was given the following Example:

Let $\mu$ be a $content$ on $\mathcal{A}$ $(algebra)$. For $n\in \mathbb{N}, A_{k} \in \mathcal{A}$ show that:

$$\mu(\cup^{n}_{j=1}{A_j)} \le \sum^{n}_{j=1}\mu(A_j)$$

Now, intuitively, this makes sense, since the Sets don't have to be disjoint. My approach would be as following:

*Assume, that $\mu(A_j)< \infty$, otherwise the proof is trivial.* *Observe, that $ \mu(A_i \cup A_j) = \mu(A_i) + \mu(A_j) - \mu(A_i \cap A_j)$*
*it follows, that*$$\mu(\cup^{n}_{j=1}A_j) \le \mu(\cup^{n-1}_{j=1}A_j) \ +\ \mu(A_n) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   (*)$$
*The inequality above is true, since there can exists a $x \in A_{n-1} \cap A_n$ $\implies \mu(A_{n-1}\cup A_n) \le \mu(A_{n-1}) + \mu(A_n)$*

*One can extend $(*)$ to:*

*$$\mu(\cup^{n}_{j=1}{A_j)} \le \mu(A_1) + \mu(A_2) + \ ...\ + \mu(A_{n-1})  \ + \ \mu(A_n) = \sum^n_{j=1}  \mu(A_j)$$*

*I don't know, if such a proof for the Subadditivity-Example would be theoretically correct.*

Thank you guys!

Comment: For me it is definitely not clear how you come to the conclusion $(*)$.

Comment: That being said, the classical proof just starts with $A_1,\dots, A_n$, makes them disjoint (so we lose some mass) and this gives the inequality.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Because the sets aren't disjoint, there exists more Volume, if I add the last set $$A_n$$ to the Union. My Logic was, that I could do this with all Sets.

Comment: @QuantumSpace I know what the classical proof is...the problem I am having is, that I don't want to just read and remember all the classical proofs that I might need. I want to improve my proving skills in order to be able to come to such proofs on my own, so that is what I am practicing :/